# Are these birds in video real? What are they called?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I recently came acroos this video   :  https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1053324651468913&id=492140647587319

I want to know whether these birds are real or edited? If they're real,  what are their names?

Comment: The problem here is that your question depends on a video on another site and so is not a self-contained question here. Unless you can at least present some screen captures to illustrate the problem, it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Have been to many stackexchange sites,  have seen many such questions (& answers,  too), so I thought it was okay...  Moreover, taking ss would probably be illegal....!

Comment: I don't care who else breaks the rules. I am only concerned with applying them, and educating others to apply them, to questions I encounter as a reviewer on this site. There are many more violations than there are reviewers to deal with them. If you can't post a question in a way you consider legal don't post it at all. I vote to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @David Actually, I would like to keep this question open.  It could have been better, but I think the answerer gave us sufficient context  so it will continue to be useful for people.

Comment: @tbek — OK. I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: Somehow I found my way back to this question and would like to apologize for not asking the question in best possible way. However I'd like to note that I didn't even know, at that time, that I can find those birds over their (or the fact that such beautiful creatures do exist, and hence my question) and my question was motivated by the opportunity to search about them if at all they were real. I'd like to thank the user24284 for showing me "where to search" also.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, they are real, that's not a CGI. That footage belongs to [The Cornell Lab of Ornithology](http://birdsofparadiseproject.org/?__hssc=75100365.1.1502546357369&__hstc=75100365.328ef95cc9b5c9d93a6001ad44bfb29a.1502546357369.1502546357369.1502546357369.1&__hsfp=2601939632&hsCtaTracking=50590417-7c6b-4271-8ade-aa04723d1ae1%7Cd6084484-0a7e-452d-9a89-c37e4ceeb61e), and those are [birds-of-paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird-of-paradise).

The first one is a [Wilson's Bird of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_bird-of-paradise) (*Diphyllodes respublica*). Here is an image of it:

[image]

The second one, showing a courtship display, is a [Superb Bird of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superb_bird-of-paradise) (*Lophorina superba*). Here is an image of it:

[image]

And the courtship display:

[image]

The third one is a [King Bird of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_bird-of-paradise) (*Cicinnurus regius*). Here is an image of it:

[image]

The next one is the [Wahnes's parotia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahnes%27s_parotia) (*Parotia wahnesi*). Here is a picture of it:

[image]

The last one is a [King of Saxony Bird of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_Saxony_bird-of-paradise) (*Pteridophora alberti*). Here is its picture:

[image]

Finally, here is the only *correct* way (just kidding) to watch any video with birds of paradise: narrated by David Attenborough! Have a look:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWfyw51DQfU

Comment: At this point, I wanna tell you, you just left a couple or so birds more...really waiting to know more about all of 'em! And +1 of course ;)